# changing css classes by analyzing the array by JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, css-selectors

first try here.
Im quite new into web development and most of the time busy doin frontendstuff based on CSS, html, the typical mark-up/styling part of the game. I just styled some dropcaps, which shall change their behaviour depending on the content in the span. so as far as '12' takes more space than '1' or even '#12', ive got multiple css classes which change the style. the goal is to write some piece of JS which analyzes how many and which characters i've put in the span, and therefore attach a class to it. easy right?

well im not that much into JS, mostly getting along with the basic stuff so ill need some recommondation where to change or adjust the code to get better.

this is how i've got so far:

```
function capsChange(){

var spanLength = document.getElementsByClassName('.dropcap.circle').value.length
var spanContent = document.getElementsByClassName ('.dropcap.cirle')

if (spanLength = 2 && spanContent.includes('#')) { 

    spanContent.classList.add('oneplusdot');
}

else if (spanLength = 1) { 

    spanContent.classList.add('onealone'); 
}

else if (spanLength = 3 && spanContent.includes('.') ) { 

    spanContent.classList.add('twoplusdot');
}

else if(spanLength = 3 && spanContent.includes('#') ) { 

    spanContent.classList.add('twoplusone');
}

else if(spanLength = 2 && spanContent.includes("#" || '.') == false ) { 

    spanContent.classList.add('twoalone');
}
}
```

Thanks in advance and please excuse my (most likely) bad writing in this.

Comment: _"this is how i've got so far"_ - Okay, but what's the problem? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, but you want `==` or `===` for comparison

Comment: `.includes("#" || '.')` - You definitely should have another look at how the different operators work and how you have to use them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Though you haven't posted any problem specific to JS. It's an advise to check short circuiting for better code readability and to avoid nested conditional statements.

```
capsChange() {
    var spanLength = document.getElementsByClassName('.dropcap.circle').value.length
    var spanContent = document.getElementsByClassName('.dropcap.cirle')
    switch (spanLength) {
        case 1:
            spanContent.classList.add('onealone');
            break;

        case 2:
            if (spanContent.includes('#')) {
                spanContent.classList.add('oneplusdot');
                break;
            }
            if (!spanContent.includes('.')) {
                spanContent.classList.add('twoalone');
            }
            break;
        
        case 3:
            if (spanContent.includes('#')) {
                spanContent.classList.add('twoplusone');
                break;
            }
            if (spanContent.includes('.')) {
                spanContent.classList.add('twoplusdot');
            }
            break;
    }
```

Comment: thank you guys for the advice. Im not really into all the operators and made my way to the code by research on the web, which is why i wanted you guys to have a look upon it and push the good advice (on working operators, or syntax or whatever) straight back to me. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Just to make code less you can see this one..

```
function capsChange(){

var spanContent = document.getElementsByClassName('.dropcap.circle');
var spanLength = spanContent.value.length;

if (spanLength === 1) { 
    spanContent.classList.add('onealone'); 
}
else if(spanLength === 2){
    spanContent.classList.add(!spanContent.includes("#" || '.') && 'twoalone');
    spanContent.classList.add(spanContent.includes('#') && 'oneplusdot');
}
else if(spanLength === 3){
    spanContent.classList.add(spanContent.includes('.') && 'twoplusdot');
    spanContent.classList.add(spanContent.includes('#') && 'twoplusone');
}
```

}